# How do I import custom components in QtCreator when I'm using Cmake to create a project?

Tags: qt, cmake, qml, qt-creator, qt6.4.1

I am creating an app using QtCreator and I'm using Cmake. I created a folder called ui and in the folder a file that contains qml code for a custom coponent. When I write this code in the main.qml  'import "ui/BottomBar"' it works perfectly without indicating any errors, I also write code in the main qml file to implement the component and show it on the window, I t also works. The problem is that when I build and run the project, it shows an output that there's no such file or directory (the one I imported). Help me know how to solve and make the imports work perfectly because this project heavily depends on it.

I checked the documentation and it says I put this statement in the CmakeLists.txt file:

```
set(QML_IMPORT_PATH ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/qml ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/imports CACHE STRING "" FORCE).
```

I replaced the /qml part with ui (my folder) and expected it to work but I kept getting more errors, I guess there's something else I need to do.

Comment: Please add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you are trying to explain.